# Como abrir uma nova página ao clicar na linha da tabela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei uma página que exibe dados  do banco de dados em uma tabela, gerada através do plugin dataTables (Jquery). Ela funciona da seguinte maneira: quando o usuário clica na linha da tabela, ele é redirecionado para uma página de edição.

A linha do código que faz esse redirecionamento é:

```
$("#tabela-estacoes td").click(function() {
    window.location = "editar-estacoes-trabalho.php?id=" + $(this).parent("tr").attr('identifier');
});
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: como eu faço para ao invés de redirecionar a página, abrir esses dados em uma nova aba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta fazer assim:

```
$("#tabela-estacoes td").click(function() {
    var identifier = $(this).parent("tr").attr('identifier');
    var $form = $("<form></form>");
    $form.attr({
        action: "http://endereco/editar-estacoes-trabalho.php",
        target: 'blank'
    });

    $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+identifier+'">');

    $('body').append($form);
    $form.submit().remove();
});
```

Comment: Fernando, é quase isso! Adicionei seu código e testei, abre uma nova página da maneira que eu preciso, monta o layout da página mas não exibe o conteúdo da linha que cliquei  pq  não está setando o id . O final do link da nova página fica:  editar-estacoes-trabalho.php?id=      Faz ideia do que pode ser??

Comment: Não sei bem o que pode ser, mas acho é relacionado a construção da URL pelo browser, modifiquei o exemplo, agora passa o valor de _identifier_

Comment: Deu certo! Era exatamente isso que eu precisava!!! Muito obrigada pela ajuda, Fernando.

Answer (score 2):

Eu faço desta forma:

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Abrir em outra aba</button>

  <script>
  function myFunction() {
    window.open('http://www.terra.com.br', '_newtab');
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sou muito bom com Javascript mas eu costumo usar o seguinte

```
<td onclick="location.href='$linkQueVcQuerCarregar'">CONTEUDO DA CELULAR</td>
```

Costuma funcionar como solicitado, mas eu ainda faria uma função por DRY pra não ficar feio, tipo assim

`$("#tabela-estacoes td").click(function() {
window.open("editar-estacoes-trabalho.php?id=" + $(this).parent("tr").attr('identifier');", '_blank');
});`

assim ficaria bonito e estaria já aplicado a todos os `<td>` da tabela `#tabela-estacoes`; Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: HananiaMizrahi, obrigada pela resposta. Eu uso esse código no meu serviço e agora não tenho como testar... Mas só alterando o window.location  para location.href  a página atual vai permanecer sendo exibida e os dados da linha que eu selecionei abrirão em nova aba?

Comment: Pra abrir em uma nova PAGINA vc troca location.href e bota window.open('LINK', '_blank') ai funciona como vc quer.

Comment: Eu já fiz dessa maneira e não deu certo  $("#tabela-estacoes td").click(function() {
window.open = ("editar-estacoes-trabalho.php?id=" +," _blank") $(this).parent("tr").attr('identifier');

Comment: Nem desta maneira $("#tabela-estacoes td").click(function() { window.open = ("editar-estacoes-trabalho.php?id=" +," _blank");

Comment: Amigo, a função window.open() solicita 2 parametros, que são o primeiro o link que vc quer abrir, e o segundo que é o modo como esse link será aberto, no caso _blank... tipo assim -> window.open('http://meulink.com.br','_blank');

Comment: Dei uma editada na resposta acima, tenta ver se funciona, aqui rodou bacaninha! No mais, certifique-se que o framework jquery esteja sendo chamado...